# Set the Y position of the X axis in OxyPlot

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I am plotting a basic LineSeries with the excellent OxyPlot library :

[image]
I can't find how to set the X axis to be centered at the 0 Y value and not at the bottom of the PlotArea.

My code-behind is as follow :

```
Model = new PlotModel();
LineSeries RightingLever = new LineSeries();
RightingLever.Title = "Righting Lever";
// adding points
Model.Series.Add(RightingLever);
PlotView.Model = Model;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the `PositionAtZeroCrossing` property of the `Axis` class.

```
foreach (var axis in Model.Axes)
{
    axis.PositionAtZeroCrossing = true;
    axis.AxislineStyle = LineStyle.Automatic;
}
```

[image]